# Keeping graphs of terminated Kubernetes pods in Prometheus/Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I love using Prometheus/Grafana to monitor and tune resource usage on my Kubernetes clusters. When pods are terminated, however, the graphs are disposed of it seems.

I am looking for a solution to this problem.

For informed decisions on how to tune resource requests I need history to be kept.

Does anybody know how to keep graphs for deleted Kubernetes pods in Prometheus/Grafana.

I am currently using this deployment:
https://itnext.io/kubernetes-monitoring-with-prometheus-in-15-minutes-8e54d1de2e13

Answer (score 5):

The metrics for deleted pods still exists on the Prometheus Time Series Database. The problem is that the Grafana dashboards imported from [kubernetes-mixin](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin) create the pod list when loading the dashboards.

To change this in Grafana, open the `Variables` menu, then change `$pod` variable to refresh `On Time Range Change`:

[image]

Go back to the panels and change the time range (e.g., to "This Month"). The deleted pods for that period should be listed in the dropdown menu.